# Sending Bitcoin from my wallet to a different bitcoin address

Tags: blockchain

When I want to send bitcoin from my wallet to another bitcoin address in blockchain.info, I must to have a private key. How I can obtain a private key?

Comment: You want to send to another address of yours, or to an address of some other person?

Answer (score 1):

When completing a transaction via bitcoin, you *never* need the target's private key.  Never give your private key to anyone.  NEVER.  The private key is the only secret you have that protects your bitcoin.  If you give your private key to someone else, they can "spend" your bitcoin.

When sending money to someone, you simply need an "address"; the recipient should provide you with that address.  If you are attempting to send money from one BlockChain.info wallet to another waller on BlockChain.info, you can get the target address by clicking on the "Request" link inside your wallet.

See [this](https://support.blockchain.com/hc/en-us/articles/207528856-Requesting-Bitcoin) BlockChain.info support page for details.